# Changing from system() to execvp() in C shell program

Tags: c, linux, shell

I am working on writing a simple shell in C. A user inputs commands and they are stored in a two dimensional array, for example:

```
SHELL$ ls ; date ; ls
// This is parsed into the following
char* commands[1000] = {"ls", "date", "ls"};
```

I have a for loop that passes each element of the array to system if throughout my program I don't have a specific role for that input -- I do not have specific roles for ls and date:

```
if (did_not_process == 0)
    system(commands[i]);
```

Now I want to convert system() to execvp() and have the EXACT same functionality. This was my approach that did not function appropriately:

```
if (did_not_process == 0) {        
    command[0] = commands[i];
    command[1] = NULL;

    if (fork() == 0) {
        execvp(command[0], command);
    } else {
        wait(NULL); //wait for child to complete?
    }
}
```

Only problem is as I go through further iterations of the shell (a simple while loop) it prints executions sporadically and uncontrollably. The problem lies somewhere in the code I have shown, but I cannot figure out where.

Here is example output:

```
SHELL$ ls;date;ls
file
Mon Jul 16 13:42:13 EDT 2012
file
SHELL$ ls
SHELL$ file
```

Works the first time and then prints file on the same line as the shell input.

Comment: Any particular reason to not wait on the *child itself*?

Comment: system() runs tasks via a shell, so it is the shell that is actually exec'd. Still you may find it useful to look at a simple, working implemention, for example https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/libc/unistd/system.c

Comment: I believed wait(NULL) waited on the child. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Yes. It waits on *a* child, not necessarily the one you just spawned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just on general principles, you should be checking the return values of your system calls for errors:

```
int cpid = fork()
if (cpid == -1) {
    perror("fork");
} else if (cpid == 0) {
    execvp(command[0], command);
    perror("execvp");
    _exit(1);
} else {
    if (waitpid(cpid, 0, 0) < 0)
        perror("waitpid");
}
```

Comment: system(3) does more than that: it blocks SIGCHLD and disables SIGINT and SIGQUIT in the calling process. Incidentally, it is actually one of a reasons to not use it (the `system(3)`): imagine what happens when the spawned process also does that and hangs. Or just starts processes in a tight loop. So, your code can be considered better than system(3) in some situations :-)